# CameraRoll Button using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want my camera ui will have the regular Camera Roll button. The one that you have when you open the camera app. Is there a simple way doing that or I'll have to use a custom layer? Tried searching in the documentation without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an easy way to do it. You should implement your own custom toolbar to replicate the camera app behavior. You should use the overlay view property of the imagePicker. Have a look at [this link](http://www.devsrealm.com/objective-c/custom-camera-app-1/) for a possible implementation

Comment: But it's just the camera roll icon. It's already implanted in the camera app. I don't understand why they make it so difficult.